# Error: An unexpected error has occurred when running firebase login command

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

firebase login --debug
i  Firebase optionally collects CLI usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.

? Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information? Yes
i  To change your data collection preference at any time, run `firebase logout` and log in again.

Visit this URL on this device to log in:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=151882733&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9005

Waiting for authentication...

```
[2020-04-21T13:30:57.183Z] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error message is specifically giving instructions to contact Firebase support about this error.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem's solution may depend on the type of OS one is using if you are using window first run cmd as an administrator then type `firebase login` this should solve this problem and if your OS is Linux you may need to do `sudo firebase login` can be solved by

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgRgt.jpg)

Waiting for authentication...

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log

set environment variable C:\Windows\System32
and restart vs code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).